# Change Direction During Animation (using vanilla JS animations)

Tags: javascript, animation

I am looking for a way to interrupt an animation and change the direction, something like:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
var rightwards = false;
var leftKeyframe = { transform: 'translate(0)' };
var rightKeyframe = { transform: 'translate(200px, 0)' };

function toggledirection() {
    rightwards = !rightwards;

    if (rightwards) {
        elem.animate([leftKeyframe, rightKeyframe], 1000);
    } else {
        elem.animate([rightKeyframe, leftKeyframe], 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
<button onclick="toggledirection();">Toggle Direction</button>
```

However, notice how I have to define the start position of each animation, so when I interrupt a running animation the box jumps to the new start position and goes from there. I would like the box to just start from wherever it is currently [like so](http://jsbin.com/koxumaguyu/edit?html,js,output) (but this uses CSS animations, whereas I'm looking for a JS solution). The only method I have so far is to retrieve the current translation by [parsing the transform string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912684/how-to-get-value-of-translatex-and-translatey), but I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation humm, I didn't know this API. However, why not a css/js solution like the example you shared in the "like so" link?

Comment: js animations have alot more power and flexibility, and they can even be [faster](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/) :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made few tests:
 - [here (JsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/8x50qyyt/) using the element computed style to reverse the animation.
 - and [here (JsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/8x50qyyt/1/) using the animate `.reverse` native method while checking the `playState`.

In the first fiddle I started a new animation every button click so, when you reverse while it's still transitioning, the animation will require 1 second to finish even if the element is 2 px far form the destination point.

also remember that `window.getComputedStyle(element)` !== `element.style`

---

**Animation API:**
 - http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation

**getComputedStyle:**
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: didn't know about getComputedStyle, thanks for that!!